# Most runners under 10s in a single 100m race?

Tags: records, running, athletics

What is the greatest number of runners ever to have gone below 10s in a single 100m race? Has there ever been an instance of *all* runners getting below 10s?

Just found that at the 2012 Olympics it would have been all eight except that Asafa Powell pulled a muscle half way through. So seven is the highest number I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went through the IAAF site and checked the list of senior outdoor results on 100 metres men over years from 2001 until 2018 (for example, see the [results from 2016](https://www.iaaf.org/records/toplists/sprints/100-metres/outdoor/men/senior/2016?regionType=world&timing=electronic&windReading=regular&page=1&bestResultsOnly=false)).

Considering those, I checked the worst position of a runner when running below 10 s, which means that that amount of people ran below that time. These are the results:

**On 5 times, 6 men ran below 10 s** (see the *6* before the city where the championship was held; it represents the position):

- 9.98  +0.1    Tracey, Tyquendo                JAM       9.98    6  21 JUL 2018
- 9.96  +0.2    Ben Youssef MEITÉ   11 NOV 1986 CIV CIV 6       Rio de Janeiro (BRA)    14 AUG 2016
- 9.98  +1.5    Richard THOMPSON    07 JUN 1985 TTO TTO 6       London (GBR)    27 JUL 2012
- 9.97  +1.3    Justin GATLIN   10 FEB 1982 USA USA 6       Eugene (USA)    04 JUN 2011
- 9.97  0.0 Michael FRATER  06 OCT 1982 JAM JAM 6       Beijing (CHN)   16 AUG 2008

This happened in these races (by order of representation of the result, with a link to the IAAF result page):

- [London Anniversary Games 2018](http://www.letsrun.com/news/2018/07/schedule-entries-results-2018-muller-anniversary-games-2018-london-diamond-league/)
- [Rio 2016](https://www.iaaf.org/results/olympic-games/2016/the-xxxi-olympic-games-5771/men/100-metres/final/result) (Olympic Games)
- [London 2012](https://www.iaaf.org/results/olympic-games/2012/the-xxx-olympic-games-4871/men/100-metres/final/result) (Olympic Games)
- [Eugene 2011](https://www.iaaf.org/results/diamond-league-meetings/2011/prefontaine-classic-4736/men/100-metres/final/result#resultheader) (Prefontaine Classic)
- [Beijing 2008](https://www.iaaf.org/results/olympic-games/2008/the-xxix-olympic-games-3659/men/100-metres/final/result) (Olympic Games)

Notes:

- In 2012 Tyson Gay was 4th on the [Olympic Games final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_100_metres#Final) with 9.80, only that he was later on disqualified. His result was making that race the fastest ever, since 7 runners ran below 10 s. After his disqualification, this race is in a draw position with the other three races, all of them with 6 men below 10 s.
- In [1988 Seoul's World Championships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_1988_Summer_Olympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_100_metres#Final) four men ran below 10 s, only that Ben Johnson was later on disqualified. Being considered the *dirtiest race in history*, Wikipedia says for Linford Christie's result that *This was the first time anyone had broken ten seconds and finished third*.

---

Also, these are very fast races for more runners in the race:

- 10.00 -0.5    Jimmy VICAUT    27 FEB 1992 FRA FRA 8       Beijing (CHN)   23 AUG 2015
- 10.01 +0.6    Nesta CARTER    10 NOV 1985 JAM JAM 7       Bruxelles (BEL) 05 SEP 2014
- 10.01 +1.3    Richard THOMPSON    07 JUN 1985 TTO TTO 7       Eugene (USA)    04 JUN 2011
- 10.00 +0.9    Jaysuma SAIDY NDURE 01 JUL 1984 NOR NOR 7       Rieti (ITA) 29 AUG 2010
- 10.00 +0.9    Marc BURNS  07 JAN 1983 TTO TTO 7       Berlin (GER)    16 AUG 2009
- 10.00 +0.6    Kim COLLINS 05 APR 1976 SKN SKN 6       Athina (GRE)    22 AUG 2004

That is, in all of these, the result of the 7th runner was 10.00 (10.01 for 2011's result). Strangely enough, in Beijing 3 people ran on 10.00: 6th, 7th and 8th.

This happened in these races (by order of representation of the result, with a link to the IAAF result page):

- [Beijing 2015](https://www.iaaf.org/results/iaaf-world-championships-in-athletics/2015/15th-iaaf-world-championships-4875/men/100-metres/final/result) (World Championships)
- Eugene 2011 (link above) (Prefontaine Classic)
- [Bruxelles 2010](https://www.iaaf.org/results/diamond-league-meetings/2014/memorial-van-damme-5379/men/100-metres/final/result) (Memorial Van Damme)
- [Rieti 2010](https://www.iaaf.org/results/iaaf-world-challenge-meetings/2010/rieti-2010-4436/men/100-metres/final/result)
- [Berlin 2009](https://www.iaaf.org/results/iaaf-world-championships-in-athletics/2009/12th-iaaf-world-championships-in-athletics-3658/men/100-metres/final/result#resultheader) (World Championships)
- [Athina 2004](https://www.iaaf.org/results/olympic-games/2004/28th-olympic-games-3201/men/100-metres/final/result) (Olympic Games)  <sub>I am adding this since I find relevant that such a result happened years before the blooming of the Usain Bolt era</sub>

It is interesting to see how big was the impact of Usain Bolt: before his appearence, no more than 10 results would be below 10 s in a year. From his years, now the number is bigger than 50 even on odd years (that is, without World Championships nor Olympic Games).

---

I wonder if some open data source exists with all this data to do some mining, likewise for [ATP & WTA](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/16554/11439))

Comment: Another race with 6 sub 10s - the final at the London Anniversary Games 21 Jul 2018. One guy ran 10.01 and came eighth!

Comment: @Mick great one! Thanks a lot, I just appended it into the answer.